# Using Dataset with Parameters for BigQuery in Cloud Data Prep?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

I have several BigQuery datasets with daily-created tables, such as

- apples_201904010
- apples_201904009

etc.

I'd like to set up a schedule Cloud Data Prep job to process these tables each night, so using the dataset with parameters option is really appealing. When I click to replace a BigQuery dataset with dataset with parameters, I get hte following prompt with a BigQuery protocol:

[image: BigQuery path example]

Is there a way to use this setup to dynamically pull the right table each day, or do I need to pursue another path such as daily export of the tables to GCS and then using datasets with parameters there?

Answer (score 2):

To schedule Cloud Dataprep jobs that process BigQuery tables by date you have the following options:

1. Use Google Cloud Composer to create a DAG that [schedules BigQuery
   exports to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/how-to-transfer-bigquery-tables-between-locations-with-cloud-composer) and then use those exported files with
   [Dataprep Parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Create-Dataset-with-Parameters_118228628) as you have mentioned.
2. [Recommended] Skip using Dataprep Parameters altogether, and simply
   create a [customized BigQuery view as a Dataprep dataset](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-schedule-a-bigquery-etl-job-with-dataprep-b1c314883ab9).

You can then [schedule your Dataprep job](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Schedule-a-Job_118228655) in either option to run daily.

Concerning option #1, you can set the [date range](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Create-Dataset-with-Parameters_118228628#add-datetime-parameter) of the Data Prep dataset with parameters so they only accept files within a specified date range.